# Opening in RichTextBox rather than Tab name

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

```
    // add a module tab
    private void add_mod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int TabCount = 0;

        int? index = searchIndex(mod_add_textbox.Text);
        if (index == null)
        {
            RichTextBox new_rich = new RichTextBox();
            new_rich.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            TabPage NewPage = new TabPage();
            TabCount += 1;
            string DocumentText = mod_add_textbox.Text;
            NewPage.Name = DocumentText;
            NewPage.Text = DocumentText;
            NewPage.Controls.Add(new_rich);
            mod_tab.TabPages.Add(NewPage);

        }

        else
        {
            mod_tab.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(index);
        }


    }     


    private async void btn_file_note_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter="Text Documents|*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
        {
            if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
                {
                    mod_tab.SelectedTab.Text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I am getting is that when I try to open a document it is opening it into the tab name rather than the rich text box inside the tab. I have changed the "mod_tab.SelectedTab" part to the name of the rich text box within the tab however I want it so whichever tab the user has selected it opens in there. Any suggestions? thank you.

Comment: You assigned the value to the `Text` property of selected tab. Instead you should assign the value to `Text` property of `RichTextBox` or use `Load` method of `RichTextBox` to load content.

Comment: I swapped "SelectedTab" for RichTextBox and it did not help

Comment: "*It did not help*" will not help us to find the problem. You should share an error if there is any error, or let me know what's the name of rich text box which you want to set it's text. I doubt it's name is RichTextBox.

Comment: I have it so when a button is clicked it adds a new tab with a RichTextBox inside of it so it is actually called RichTextBox. I just want it to open a file to the selected tab containing a already placed RichTextBox.

Comment: So share the code which you create the tab and rich text box dynamically. Surely I can offer you some options now, but seeing the code I can guide you better.

Comment: I have just updated it with the 'add tab' code, hope you can help as I have been on this for a few hours now, thank you.

Comment: See the answer below and let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find it helpful :)

Comment: Sorry Reza kid I forgot, worked though cheers pal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned the value to the `Text` property of selected tab. Instead you should assign the value to [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `RichTextBox` or use [`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `RichTextBox` to load content. for example:

```
this.richTextBox1.Text = ....
```

Also when you create the tab and `RichTextBox` dynamically like you ar doing in your code, you can find it this way:

```
//It means: Find  all RichTextBox control which are children of mod_tab.SelectedTab
//And return first of them.

var rtb = this.mod_tab.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
rtb.Text = ...
```

Also this way:

```
//It means get the first child control of mod_tab.SelectedTab
//And convert it to RichTextBox.

var rtb = this.mod_tab.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
rtb.Text = ...
```